# PostgreSQL: Create View Name using parameter

Tags: postgresql, view, parameters

I want to parametrize the name of a view using **postgresql**.
In particular, I want to create a **view inside a function** and **use the parameter for the name of the view**.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_to_be(certain_date  date)   RETURNS void as $$

BEGIN
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW name_of_schema.test_view AS
SELECT * from test_table;   
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So the desired name of the view should be **name_of_schema.test_view_2019_07_29** after executing the function with the parameter .

However, the name should be schema-qualified - such that I could not directly pass a whole string for the name.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds strange. What exactly are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I want to call the function and get a separate table each time for each certain_date.

Comment: Why create a view for each date then? At the end you wind up with thousands of views. You could create a function that returns the data you want by applying a restriction using the passed date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds a little stange to me having a lot of views in the end, that all are defined with the same query...

But you can try and use `EXECUTE`.

```
...
EXECUTE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW name_of_schema.test_view_' || to_char(certain_date, 'yyyy_mm_dd') || ' AS SELECT * from test_table;';
...
```